# AngularJS Interceptor ResponseError response undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this handler that I built to handle $http requests.

It looks like this:

```
.service('ApiHandler', ['$q', '$http', '$injector', 'apiUrl', 'ErrorService', 'toastr', function ($q, $http, $injector, apiUrl, errorService, toastr) {

    // Private function to build our request
    var buildRequest = function (url, method, data, params) {

        // Create our deferred promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Create the model
        var model = {
            method: method,
            url: apiUrl + url,
            data: data,
            params: params
        };

        console.log(model);

        // Build our request
        $http(model).then(function (response) {

            console.log('we have a response');

            // Resolve our response
            deferred.resolve(response.data || response);

        // If we have an error
        }, function (error) {

            console.log('we have an error');

            // Process our error
            processedError = errorService.process(error);

            // Display our error
            toastr.error(processedError.message, processedError.title);
        });

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // GET
    this.get = function (url, params) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'GET', null, params);
    };

    // POST
    this.post = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'POST', data);
    };

    // PUT
    this.put = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'PUT', data);
    };

    // DELETE
    this.delete = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'DELETE', data);
    };
}])
```

The idea is that when someone performs any http request, if the request is successful it will display the data (only the data) and if it errors for what ever reason, it will process the error and display a nice error message.

This was working, but I am unsure why it has stopped.
I purposefully put an error in my API to force a 500 Internal Server Error and in chrome I can see this:

> > GET http://localhost:54326/orders?orderNumber=M0002663&readCoreHistory=true 500 (Internal Server Error)

The problem is, after I get this error, I expect to see **we have an error** in the console, but I don't. I get **we have a response**.

Does anyone know why the success handler is being hit rather than the error handler?

**Update**

I now know what was causing the issue.
I had an interceptor that looked like this:

```
.factory('AuthInterceptorService', ['$location', function ($location) {

    // The request function
    var request = function (config) {

        // Get our stored auth data
        var authData = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.authorizationData);

        // Set our headers to the request headers or a new object
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        // If we have any auth data
        if (authData) {

            // Set our authorization header
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }

        // Return our config
        return config;
    };

    // The response function
    var responseError = function (response) {

        console.log('error handler');

        // If our response status is unauthorized
        if (response.status === 401) {

            // Redirect to the login screen
            $location.path('/security/login');
        }
    };

    return {
        request: request,
        responseError: responseError
    };
}])
```

As you the responseError function is not returning / rejecting anything, so I changed it to this:

```
.factory('AuthInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'ErrorService', function ($q, $location, errorService) {

    // The request function
    var request = function (config) {

        // Get our stored auth data
        var authData = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.authorizationData);

        // Set our headers to the request headers or a new object
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        // If we have any auth data
        if (authData) {

            // Set our authorization header
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }

        // Return our config
        return config;
    };

    // The response function
    var responseError = function (response) {

        console.log('error handler');

        // If our response status is unauthorized
        if (response.status === 401) {

            // Redirect to the login screen
            $location.path('/security/login');
        } else {

            // Process our error
            var error = errorService.process(response);

            console.log(error);

            // Reject our response
            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    };

    return {
        request: request,
        responseError: responseError
    };
}])
```

And I changed my API handler to this:

```
.service('ApiHandler', ['$q', '$http', 'apiUrl', 'toastr', function ($q, $http, apiUrl, toastr) {

    // Private function to build our request
    var buildRequest = function (url, method, data, params) {

        // Create our deferred promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Create the model
        var model = {
            method: method,
            url: apiUrl + url,
            data: data,
            params: params
        };

        //console.log(model);

        // Build our request
        $http(model).success(function (response) {

            //console.log('we have a response');

            // Resolve our response
            deferred.resolve(response);

        // If we have an error
        }).error(function (error) {

            console.log('we have an error');

            console.log(error);

            // Display our error
            toastr.error(error.message, error.title);

            deferred.reject();
        });

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // GET
    this.get = function (url, params) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'GET', null, params);
    };

    // POST
    this.post = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'POST', data);
    };

    // PUT
    this.put = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'PUT', data);
    };

    // DELETE
    this.delete = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'DELETE', data);
    };
}])
```

Now the error handler is actually being invoked, but the error parameter is undefined. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try doing like that :

```
$http.get('/someURL').success(function(data, status, header, config) {
    // success handler
}).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
    // error handler
});
```

Comment: If I do it like that, the success handler isn't called when there is an error, but neither is the error handler. I have no idea why :/

Answer (score 0):

If I changed my ApiHandler back to this:

```
.service('ApiHandler', ['$q', '$http', 'apiUrl', 'toastr', function ($q, $http, apiUrl, toastr) {

    // Private function to build our request
    var buildRequest = function (url, method, data, params) {

        // Create our deferred promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Create the model
        var model = {
            method: method,
            url: apiUrl + url,
            data: data,
            params: params
        };

        // Build our request
        $http(model).then(function (response) {

            // Resolve our response
            deferred.resolve(response.data);

        // If we have an error
        }, function (response) {

            // Display our error
            toastr.error(response.message, response.title);

            deferred.reject();
        });

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // GET
    this.get = function (url, params) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'GET', null, params);
    };

    // POST
    this.post = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'POST', data);
    };

    // PUT
    this.put = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'PUT', data);
    };

    // DELETE
    this.delete = function (url, data) {
        return buildRequest(url, 'DELETE', data);
    };
}])
```

it works fine.

I could also do a

```
.success(function (response) {

    return response;
}).catch(function (response) {

    toastr.error(response.message, response.title);
});
```

and that would work too.